# Using chrome and puppeteer with multiple browsers

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer.
I need to load multiples pages and inject a javascript.

I am creating two browsers, with one page(tab) each one and the javascript injected.

I have a node server with routes to each page loaded.

I named a session to each page with '100' and '101'. Two userdata folders(100 and 101) are created after run the app. These sessions are also used to separate the routes.

The browsers are correctly created , without problem.

My problem is when I consume a route, node server allways return the same result to both pages:

If I test using Postman or an other chrome  browser with the next:

```
http://localhost:3007/teste100/getMyNumber 
and    http://localhost:3007/teste101/getMyNumber
```

They are returning the same value.
But the values are differentes to each browser page.
It seems the page is not been considered on request and It returns the same result to both pages. But, as I said the function "getMyNumber" should be returning differents values to each page. My sample function uses local storage but i have many others not using local storage and all have the same problem.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

I suspect about something I am not passing the correct browser page to route.
But, I don´t find the error.

//server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const port = 3001
const host = 'http://localhost'
const callbackUrl = `${host}:${port}`;

const browser_pages = {};
startUp = async (sessionId) => {
    if (browser_pages[sessionId]) return browser_pages[sessionId];
    let clientBrowser = require('./src/clientbrowser')({}, sessionId)
    let cb = await clientBrowser.startWhats(sessionId || "user_data");
    let page = cb.getPage();
    browser_pages[sessionId] = cb;
    const troutes = require('./src/routes/testroutes')(page)
    app.use('/teste' + sessionId, troutes)
}
startUp('100');
startUp('101');
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on ${callbackUrl}...`);
});
```

//clientBrowser.js

```
const path = require('path');
const EventEmitter = require('events');
....
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

class ClientBrowser extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(options, sessionId) {
        super();
        this.options = fUtils.mergeDefault(DefaultOptions, options);
        this.app = app;
        this.pPage = null;
    }
    getPage = () => {
        return this.pPage;
    }
    createBrowser = async (sessionId) => {
        let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            userDataDir: path.join(process.cwd(), sessionId || 'session'),
            args: DEFAULT_CHROMIUM_ARGS,
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            devtools: false,
            defaultViewport: null
        });
        return browser;
    }


    LoadPageWhatsApp = async (page) => {
        page.setUserAgent(UserAgent);
        await page.setBypassCSP(true);
        await page.setViewport({
            width: 800,
            height: 900
        })
        await page.goto(WEB_WHATS_APP, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
            timeout: 0
        })
        return page;
    }

    initWhatsApp = async (sessionId) => {
        let browser = await this.createBrowser(sessionId);
        let pages = await browser.pages();
        let page = pages[0];
        await this.LoadPageWhatsApp(page);
        return page;
    }

    startWhats = async (sessionId) => {
        const page = await this.initWhatsApp(sessionId);
        this.pPage = page;
        let fpath = './web/teste.js';
        //inject test script
        await page.addScriptTag({ path: require.resolve(fpath) });
        console.log("Injected Script:" + path.basename(fpath));
        return this;
    }
}
module.exports = (params, sessionId) => { return new ClientBrowser(params, sessionId)}
```

//testroutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function (page) {
    router.get('/getMyNumber', async (req, res) => {
        const cc = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return getMyNumber();
        });
        console.log(cc);
        res.send({ "data": cc });
    });

    return router;
}
```

//teste.js

```
function getMyNumber() {
    return localStorage.getItem('last-wid');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is causing the problems:

```
module.exports = function (page) {
    router.get('/getMyNumber', async (req, res) => {
        const cc = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return getMyNumber();
        });
        console.log(cc);
        res.send({ "data": cc });
    });

    return router;
}
```

You actually set this route twice. I know it looks like you set two different paths because of your `app.use('/teste' + sessionId, troutes)` line. But really you set two different paths to point to the same `router`. Your router object is the same for both because the object is coming from the same module `require('./src/routes/testroutes')`

Quick fix: Pass page and sessionId to make an unique url with route.get. 
For example: `router.get('/getMyNumber'+ sessionId,....` or `router.get('/'+ sessionId + '/getMyNumber',....`

What your current code is sets up to do is make two middleware calls for `/getMyNumber` route. router.get actually passes a third parameter `next` to your callback. `function. ('/getMyNumber', async (req, res, next)`. If you call next() in you function instead of res.send({...}) the other `'/getMyNumber'` will be called.

To clarify the last paragraph your code is acting like this:

```
router.get('/getMyNumber', [cbPage1, cbPage2])
```

### **UPDATE:**

By creating the page when the route is called you won't have the page close problem. You can then save the result of your call to `browser_pages[sessionId]`.
This change also will give you unique routes for each call. Also, by setting the route with `app` you don't have to deal with `express.Router()`.

```
startUp = async(sessionId, app) => {
    app.get(baseUrl + sessionId +'/getMyNumber', async (req, res) => {
        let clientBrowser = require('./src/clientbrowser')({}, sessionId)
        let cb = await clientBrowser.startWhats(sessionId || "user_data");
        let page = cb.getPage();
        const cc = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return getMyNumber();
        });
        console.log(cc);
        browser_pages[sessionId] = cc; // save the result of the session
        res.send({ "data": cc });
    });
}
```

Comment: @123 No, it's not the cause for the same result. I have other functions and all return the same values. For sample, I have a function to get all contatcts from whatsapp. I use two mobiles one to each page. When I inject the script I have allways the same result. The cell mobile has differents contacts list. So, the problem is not  local storage.

Comment: @123, Thank you I will try it. But, now I have to repeat sessionId two times to access the route. I have to use localhost:/3007/test100/getMyNumber/100. It´s ugly. Do you see something to make it better?

Comment: @123 Thank you very much for your help. I am accepting your answer.

Comment: @123 One question more please. The first you solved. In my code I use "const troutes = require('./src/routes/testroutes')(page)", but sometimes the "page" is closed and invalidated. Then I create a new "page" and I use again "const troutes = require('./src/routes/testroutes')(page)". But the route remember the old page closed   and the route doesn´t work. Is there something I have to do in order to avoid it?

Comment: Is there a way to delete the old route and use the new route with the correct page params?

Comment: I don't think you can delete the old route. (it might be possible but not officially documented)

I think a little change to your design might fix both the routing and the page closing. 

I will update my answer with new startup function for your //server.js file.

I realize it might not work for what you are trying to do but it might give you a new way to look at the problem

Comment: Thank tou Very much